# Error compiling with GLib

Tags: c, compilation, libraries, glib

I'm pretty new to C programming, and am trying to work through the exercises in '21st Century C' second edition. I'm stuck on page 202, Example 9-7, unicode.c. This example starts with:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <locale.h> //setlocale
#include "string_utilities.h"
#include "stopif.h"

//Frees instring for you--we can't use it for anything else.
char *localstring_to_utf8(char *instring){
    GError *e=NULL;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); //get the OS's locale.
    char *out = g_locale_to_utf8(instring, -1, NULL, NULL, &e);
    free(instring); //done with the original
    Stopif(!out, return NULL, "Trouble converting from your locale to UTF-8.");
    Stopif(!g_utf8_validate(out, -1, NULL), free(out); return NULL,
            "Trouble: I couldn't convert your file to a valid UTF-8 string.");
    return out;
}
```

When I try to compile it with:

```
c99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -Wall -O3 -lglib-2.0 unicode.c string_utilities.o   -o unicode
```

I get errors such as:

```
$ c99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -Wall -O3 -lglib-2.0 unicode.c string_utilities.o   -o unicode
/tmp/ccBDQFiH.o: In function `localstring_to_utf8':
/home/kevin/21st_Century_C/ch09/unicode.c:29: undefined reference to `g_locale_to_utf8'
/home/kevin/21st_Century_C/ch09/unicode.c:32: undefined reference to `g_utf8_validate'
/tmp/ccBDQFiH.o: In function `main':
/home/kevin/21st_Century_C/ch09/unicode.c:48: undefined reference to `g_utf8_strlen'
```

This seems to indicate that the Glib library is not found, but the compiler didn't complain about this, and the Glib libraries and include files are right where I specified on the command line. I've installed the libglib2.0-dev package in addition to the libglib2.0 package (all installed with 'sudo apt-get ..'). 'pkg-config' seems to find glib-2.0 just fine.

This is all on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 system.

I can't figure out how to correct this error, and don't understand why it can't find the specific Glib functions, if it finds the glib include and lib files.

Comment: What about specifying `-lglib-2.0` after the object files?

Comment: @CamiloBravoValdes: No joy: 'kevin@kevin-asrock:~/21st_Century_C/ch09$ c99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -Wall -O3 -lglib-2.0 unicode.c string_utilities.o -lglib-2.0. -o unicode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
kevin@kevin-asrock:~/21st_Century_C/ch09$ c99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -Wall -O3 unicode.c string_utilities.o -lglib-2.0. -o unicode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$`

Comment: @SeanBright: Still no joy: `cc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu11  `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`  unicode.c string_utilities.o   -o unicode` gives same errors

Comment: And if you include the location of the library with `-L/path/to/glib`?

Comment: @CamiloBravoValdés: pkg-config doesn't return anything: `$ pkg-config --libs-only-L glib-2.0
 
kevin@kevin-asrock:~/21st_Century_C/ch09$ 
`

Comment: @SeanBright: Yep, this worked like a champ: `cc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu11 unicode.c string_utilities.o -o unicode `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` Thank you so much.

Comment: @SeanBright: If you want to enter this as the answer, I'll be glad to accept it. (Not too confident that I know how SO works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of things in the command line matter.  In general it should be something like:

```
gcc [options] [source files] [object files] [-L stuff] [-lstuff] [-o outputfile]
```

So give this a whirl instead:

```
gcc -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu11 `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` \
    unicode.c string_utilities.o `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` \
    -o unicode
```

This is also covered in the [Compiling GLib Applications](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-compiling.html) section of the [GLib Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/index.html):

```
$ cc hello.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o hello
```

Comment: Thanks, again. Now, I wonder how to get it into a make file. The author suggests: `P=unicode
objects=string_utilities.o
CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -std=gnu11 -O3
LDLIBS=`pkg-config --libs   glib-2.0`

$(P): $(objects)
' but this doesn't put the libraries in the correct place. LDADD doesn't seem to work at all, and doesn't put the libraries in the compiler command anywhere. Any way to put these in the correct order?

Comment: I take that back. This makefile works just fine: `P=unicode
objects=string_utilities.o
CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu11
LDLIBS=`pkg-config --libs   glib-2.0`

$(P): $(objects)
`  Don't know what I was thinking...